# Svelte error page different between domain.com/static and domain.com/static/

Tags: svelte, sveltekit, svelte-3

I've added an error layout to my svelte app.
If you try to access an unknown page, the error page triggers correctly.

The problem is when I try to access domain.com/static I get à 403 restricted message.

```
403 Restricted
The request url "/Users/username/Documents/QSFRONT/static" is outside of Vite serving allow list.

- /Users/username/Documents/QSFRONT/src/lib
- /Users/username/Documents/QSFRONT/src/routes
- /Users/username/Documents/QSFRONT/.svelte-kit
- /Users/username/Documents/QSFRONT/src
- /Users/username/Documents/QSFRONT/node_modules

Refer to docs https://vitejs.dev/config/#server-fs-allow for configurations and more details.
```

But if I add a trailing / at the end, domain.com/static/, I get the error page correctly.

What should I do to display the custom error page on /static directory too ?

Thanks all

Fabien

Comment: This is a web server dependent behavior. How are you serving your site?

Comment: I believe this is a `vite` specific problem that only shows up during dev phase.